# Unity3d движение как в Diablo

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Как можно реализовать движение монстров как в Diablo. А именно только на 8 сторон (по вертикали, по горизонтали и по диагонали) на мобильных устройствах, где управление с помощью джойстика на экране. Игра изометрическая, есть спрайты монстра на 8 сторон. И вот в чем проблема. Монстр движется за персонажем, например, вниз, потом персонаж смещается по диагонали и пока угол отклонения не будет достаточным монстр будет направлен вниз, а идти будет уже со смещением по диагонали. А надо как в Diablo, чтобы строго на 8 сторон.
Вот для наглядности, как оно сейчас https://youtu.be/0aQnRBAMVqE

Скрипт движения монстра:

```
public class EnemyControl : MonoBehaviour {
    private Animator anim;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        anim = this.GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        float input_x = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x;
        float input_y = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y;
        bool walkingEnemy = (Mathf.Abs(input_x) + Mathf.Abs(input_y)) > 0;

        anim.SetBool("walkingEnemy", walkingEnemy);
        if (walkingEnemy) 
        {
            anim.SetFloat("x", input_x);
            anim.SetFloat("y", input_y);

            transform.position+=new Vector3(input_x, input_y, 0).normalized*Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Скрипт этого монстра лучше показали бы, а не видео. Сейчас можно только гадать, какой у вас код и как его исправить.

Comment: добавил скрипт монстра

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно разделить оси x и y и для каждой сделать выбор значения из: 0, 0.5, 1 с +/- конечно. Для этого можно вот такую функцию округления с точностью использовать

```
public float Round(float value, float precision)
    {
        if (precision < float.Epsilon)
            return value;

        float modul = value % precision;
        float result = value - modul;
        if (result < 0)
        {
            if (-modul >= precision / 2)
                result -= precision;
        }
        else
        {
            if (modul >= precision / 2)
                result += precision;
        }

        return result;

    }
```

тогда расчет смещения по осям будет примерно так выглядеть:

```
Vector2 velocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.normalized;
float speed = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude;
float input_x = velocity.x;
float input_y = velocity.y;
input_x = Round(input_x, 0.5f);
input_y = Round(input_y, 0.5f);
Vector2 move = (new Vectro2(input_x, input_y)).normalized * velocity.magnitude;
```

ну и дальше уже используете move для получения значений x и y, теперь вектор движения у вас с углом в 45 градусов.

Comment: движение не изменилось, т.е. под 45 градусов движение идет, оно и раньше было, но при меньшем угле идет простое смещение без изменения положения

Comment: Поделитесь исходниками, попробую помочь с отладкой

Comment: имеете ввиду выложить куда-нибудь проект?

Comment: ну либо демо с примером, можно на примере шарика и кубика, чтобы можно было потестировать

Comment: вот выложил [проект](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Gi2G/JKAGEUN8X)

Comment: Во первых вы расчитываете скорость смещения основываясь на физике получая `input_x`, но при этом последней строчкой вы пытаетесь сдвинуть `transform`, что ненормально при работе с физикой. От этого она сходит с ума: вместо расчетного объект  улетает в другое место. Скорость уже на следующем кадре неадекватная. Задайте через переменную макс скорость врага и от нее считайте сдвиг. Если физика не нужна, то не трогайте rigidbody либо делайте его isKinematic. Если же физика требуется для расчета столкновений с объектами, тогда двигайте объект прикладывая силу к rigidbody.AddForce используя физику

Comment: Плюс в классе `Enemy` вы двигаете объект прикладывая к нему силы как положено для физики. Один скрипт выравнивает движение объекта относительно игрока, а другой управляет его положением в пространстве чтобы он двигался строго по заданным направлениям. Их конкуренция и дает конфликт. Приведите все к единому стилю, либо все через физику с приложением сил в нужном направлении, либо считайте сами смещение. И желательно делать это в одном месте, а так у вас логика хромает, два скрипта управляют одной и той же функцией.

Comment: а можете посмотреть еще раз [проект](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/49RM/dHNqU5gw1) правильно ли я вас понял